# Unreal Engine 4.1.2 character starts again when he touches the floor with Blueprints

Tags: touch, unreal-engine4, actor, unreal-blueprint

I want that when my character(actor) touches the floor, he will start from the starting point of the appearance using Blueprints in Unreal Engine 4.1.2

I tried to connect them(what is marked in the picture) but it was impossible

Picture

[image: 1]

Comment: You have to connect the white arrow with the other white arrow. The red boxes are for creating callbacks. You should maybe [read the docs](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.0/en-US/nodes-in-unreal-engine/#pins).

Comment: Such a basic misunderstanding suggests that you need to start with the basics and follow some tutorials. The white arrows are the ins and outs of the 'execution pulse'.